# Understanding recursive string reversal

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7

I'm using the [Python Tutorial visualize webpage](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) to try and understand the flow of this function that reverses a string:

```
text = "hello"
def reverse(text):
    if len(text) <= 1:
        return text
    else:
        return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]

print reverse(text)
```

I understand what this function does, but even with the visualizer, I'm still not quite grasping how the last line operates in the function in terms of the flow of the function as it loops through the characters in the string:

```
return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]
```

I get that by itself `reverse(text[1:])` returns `o` and that `text[0]` returns `h`

But again, not quite experienced enough to understand how the function is set up to loop through the string using `[1:]` and `[0]` — any explanation would be greatly appreciated in terms of how the final string retuned from the function is `'olleh'`

Comment: `reverse(text[1:])` (eventually) returns `'olle'`, not just `'o'`! Think about the case `len(text) == 2` and work out from there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand what it eventually returns, I'm asking for a breakdown of how you get there using the splice methods at the end of the function.

Comment: Do you mean *"slice"*? It's not clear what exactly you don't understand. And please leave the *"tags"* out of the title.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What I don't understand is how the two built in slice functions on the last line of the reverse(text) function work together to arrive at the final reversed string.

Comment: Have you tried `text[1:]` on its own? Do you know what that does?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As I mention in my post, yes, I understand how they each individually work...but not how they work together, looping through the original string

Comment: The visualiser shows you *exactly* *"how they work together"*, so I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, that's clear. See John Kugelman's response to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the sequence of recursive calls, and what they return. You'll see that `reverse("hello")` returns the result of `reverse("ello")` plus `"h"`.

```
reverse("hello")
  --> return reverse("ello") + "h"
```

So then the question is what does `reverse("ello")` return?

```
reverse("ello")
  --> return reverse("llo") + "e"
```

Continuing on...

```
reverse("llo")
  --> return reverse("lo") + "l"

reverse("lo")
  --> return reverse("o") + "l"
```

Finally, it bottoms out when `reverse("o")` is called. Here `len(text) <= 1`, and so it returns simply `"o"`.

```
reverse("o")
  --> return "o"
```

You can then work your way back up from bottom to top to calculate the return value from the original `reverse("hello")` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot John for your very illustrative answer, appreciate it. Maybe I'm not understand the order of operations at the end of the function with   return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]    why doesn't x = "llohe" after the first time through? Instead it looks like x = "ello" (and then the function works with that string on the next iteration through).

Comment: When `text` is `"hello"`, `text[1:]` is `"ello"`. For any string `s`, `s[1:]` is that same string with the first character chopped off.

Comment: But just so I'm clear, why doesn't the first iteration through the function return "elloh" instead of just "ello" — doesn't the `+ text[0]` add the 'h' onto the end of the string?

Comment: If the last line were `return text[1:] + text[0]` then it would return `"elloh"`. But it's not, it's `return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]`. That's the tricky part, that recursive call to `reverse()`. To figure out the result of this expression, you have to pause things, figure out what `reverse(text[1:])` evaluates to, then resume once you have that answer.

Comment: Thanks, your last comment really helped clear this up for me. So basically, by returning the `rev(x)` function with the added splice function inserted at the end of the `rev(x)` function, that's what makes it recursive?

Answer (score 3):

```
reverse("hello")
-> reverse("ello") + "h"
-> reverse("llo") + "e" + "h"
-> reverse("lo") + "l" + "e" + "h"
-> reverse("o") + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h"
-> "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h"
-> "olleh"
```

This is to show the purpose of the `return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]` line and its behaviour in action.

Comment: Thanks for this breakdown, appreciate it. Just to be clear on what's happening here: is the text variable for `text[0]` basically storing each character it slices off as the recursive function calls keeps cycling through the string? or is it that with each recursive call another `text[0]` is being added?×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: The `text` variable refers to a different string in every call of the `reverse` function. The `text[0]` value is actually a single-character string taken from the beginning of the `text` string.

Comment: But it seems to be accumulating in your example, right? I think that's what I'm trying to understand. How/where are all the single characters `text[0]` is chopping off the string being stored to result in the final, reversed string? First is x = "h" then x = "e" + x = "h" etc, they're adding up, no?

Comment: The `reverse` function actually obtains two strings. One by calling itself recursively, another as `text[0]`. It simply concatenates them and returns the resulting string.

Comment: Ok, so even though `text[0]` isn't being called recursively, because `text[1:]` is being called recursively (and both are being returned on the same line) the character that `text[0]` splices off each time through get added up every time the `text[1:]` is called?

Comment: Yes, we can say that. The `+` operator is where bigger string is composed from smaller strings. A very useful approach to understand any recursive function is to consider that the function already knows how to do what it's expected to do. In our case `reverse(text[1:])` simply returns reversed version of the provided string.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Why is it that the + operator moves the most recent character value spliced off with `text[0]` to the left of the original character that was spliced off instead of to the right?

Comment: Simply, put several `print` statements to your code and display individual pieces of data, for example: What's in `text`, what's in `text[0]`, what's in `text[1:]`, what's returned from the `reverse` function, what's the result of the `+` operator, and so on. Now it's your turn.